Store with custom method and reactive values
I am building a Svelte component to display a list whose items can be added to a selection. The selection itself is a store:
selectionStore.js
import {writable} from 'svelte/store';

function createSelectionStore() {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selection")) || {});

    function remove(selection, itemId, itemType) {...}

    function add(selection, item) {...}

    return {
        subscribe,
        remove: (itemId, itemType) => update(selection => remove(selection, itemId, itemType)),
        add: (item) => update(selection => add(selection, item)),
        toggleSelection: (item) => update(selection => {
            if (selection[item.type]?.[item.id]) {
                return remove(selection, item.id, item.type);
            }
            return add(selection, item);
        }),
        isSelected: (selection, item) => {
            return selection[item.type]?.hasOwnProperty(item.id) || false;
        },
        length: (selection, itemType) => {
            return Object.keys(selectedItems[itemType]).length ?? 0
        },
    };
}
export const selectionStore = createSelectionStore();

The store is then imported in the components:
RecordList.svelte
<script>
    import Record from "./Record.svelte";
    import { selectionStore } from "./selectionStore.js";
    export let records = [];

    $: selectionLength = selectionStore.length(false);
</script>

<p>Number of selected items: {selectionLength}</p>

{#if records.length !== 0}
    <div>
        {#each records as item (item.id)}
            <Record {item}/>
        {/each}
    </div>
{/if}

Record.svelte
<script>
    import { selectionStore } from './selectionStore.svelte';
    export let item;

    $: isSelected = selectionStore.isSelected(item);
</script>

<div class="item">
    {item.item}
    <button on:click={() => selectionStore.toggleSelection(item)}>
        {isSelected ? 'Remove from' : 'Add to'} selection
    </button>
</div>

The issue I am facing is that isSelected and selectionLength are not reactive, even though toggleSelection() seem to work. I know that I am not structuring my store properly but I cannot find the right way to do it.

Edit
Here what I ended doing, thank you very much for all your help!
selectionStore.js
import {writable} from 'svelte/store';

function createSelectionStore() {
    const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selection")) || {});

    function remove(selection, itemId, itemType) {...}

    function add(selection, item) {...}

    return {
        subscribe,
        remove: (itemId, itemType) => update(selection => remove(selection, itemId, itemType)),
        add: (item) => update(selection => add(selection, item)),
        toggleSelection: (item) => update(selection => {
            if (selection[item.type]?.[item.id]) {
                return remove(selection, item.id, item.type);
            }
            return add(selection, item);
        }),
        isSelected: derived(selection, $selection =>
            item => $selection[item.type]?.hasOwnProperty(item.id) || false
        ),
        nbSelected: derived(selection, $selection =>
            itemType => Object.keys(selectedItems[itemType]).length ?? 0
        ),
    };
}
export const selectionStore = createSelectionStore();

RecordList.svelte
<script>
    import Record from "./Record.svelte";
    import { selectionStore } from "./selectionStore.js";
    const { nbSelected } = selectionStore;
    export let records = [];
</script>

<p>Number of selected items: {$nbSelected("Records")}</p>

{#if records.length !== 0}
    <div>
        {#each records as item (item.id)}
            <Record {item}/>
        {/each}
    </div>
{/if}

Record.svelte
<script>
    import { selectionStore } from './selectionStore.svelte';
    const { isSelected } = selectionStore;
    export let item;
</script>

<div class="item">
    {item.item}
    <button on:click={() => selectionStore.toggleSelection(item)}>
        {$isSelected(item) ? 'Remove from' : 'Add to'} selection
    </button>
</div>


Would not recommend global state (like the store instance), it can cause security/privacy issues if SSR is used since the instance is shared accross all users. Instead I would create the store instance in some high up component and set it as context.

Everything that should be reactive needs to be a store.
In the case of these functions, you need a derived that depends on the store holding the selection data.
const selection = writable(...);
const { subscribe, set, update } = selection;

const isSelected = derived(selection, $selection =>
  item => $selection[item.type]?.hasOwnProperty(item.id) || false
);

...

return { subscribe, isSelected, ... }

<script>
  import { selectionStore } from './selectionStore.js';

  export let item;
  
  const { isSelected } = selectionStore; // required for accessing store via $
  $: itemSelected = $isSelected(item); // or just inline in template
</script>

REPL example
(This will be a lot more simple in Svelte 5 with runes rather than stores. Functions that access state will be reactive by default.)

Demo: SvelteLab
I assumed a lot though in the structure of your selection data
You can change your "length" function to this, basically turning it into a get() function that re-calls the store to get the new values
...
get length() {
    const store = get(this);
    return store.length ?? 0
},
...

And where you use it will have to change to
<p>Number of selected items: {$selectionStore.length}</p>

And I'm assuming your store is an array? If so, your isSelected function can be removed all together, and you can check to see if the current Record is in the array using .includes()
{$selectionStore.includes(item) ? 'Remove from' : 'Add to'} selection

